# Getting a square wave as a output of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, waveform, square, loop-gain

I have the following op-amp circuit and i am trying to find out what is the open loop gain.

In order to make this simulation properly, we need to make sure that the
DC operation of the amplifier is the correct one. Applying negative feedback is a
possibility, since it is capable of automatically set the right operation point, but it
needs to operate only at DC, otherwise the open-loop gain could not be measured. To acomplish that i used the configuration shown below.

[image]

The problem is that the ouput I am getting is a square wave and I can't understand why. Isn't it supposed to be a sinusoidal wave like the input? I already applied several amplitudes do the input but the output is always the same.

[image]

Input wave: green

Ouptut wave: blue

Comment: 1. Why are you using an LC divider for the feedback? 2. Why are you using *any* feedback if you are trying to measure open-loop? 3. If you do get a correct open-loop configuration at what input signal level would you expect the output to saturate? Maybe [edit] your thoughts into your question rather than post them in the comments.

Comment: Man, you are using ~3V input signal to find an open-loop gain? For poor 80db (==*10^4) amp non-clipped output must be a ~30kV!
Try to set input to uV range.

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is that the ouput I am getting is a square wave and I
> can't understand why. Isn't it supposed to be a sinusoidal wave like
> the input? I already applied several amplitudes do the input but the
> output is always the same.*

The output amplitude is too high and the sinewave is clipping. Basically the op-amp cannot supply an output voltage bigger than its power rails minus 1 to 4 volts (op-amp dependent). Your closed loop gain is rather large at 5 kHz (\$1+\omega^2 LC\$). Do the math.

Comment: you're right. i tried to plot some other frequency and amplitude values. For really low frequencies the gain will be 1, and for high frequencies it will happen what i showed before. Then i tried f=1Hz and A=10uV, with this values i got a sine wave for the output, obtaining a gain of 394k. I guess it's working the right way now right?

Comment: @Aleat it's working the way I would expect it to given the schematic you drew. Whether this is what you want or need is entirely a different matter.